# How to save an image-file on server through Java applet?

Tags: java, image, applet, paint

I have a paint application that runs as a Java applet. I need to save the contents of the canvas on server machine in any image-format typically PNG. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested by the code I wrote for Processing, which is basically Java code.
[Re: save to web --- image export](http://processing.org/discourse/yabb_beta/YaBB.cgi?board=Syntax;action=display;num=1212658813;start=15#15). Earlier in the thread I explain some precautions to be taken with such application (to avoid flooding a server from a malicious user) and I give the corresponding PHP code.

Comment: That code worked well for me. What I was looking for was a way to export the canvas content. I did that using the Canvas class in g2d library.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do two things:

1. Generate an PNG image file in your applet - [Writing/Saving an Image](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html)
2. Post the image file to some server-side CGI/servlet which will store the image - [How do I upload a file to my servlet or JSP?](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=160)

What are you running on the server?  PHP? Rails? JSP? .NET?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll go through the links & BTW, I'm using PHP.